# Why I can't reach to the value exactly that place on python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

```
def matrix():
    rows = 10
    columns = 9

    arr = [[0]*columns]*rows
    file = open("blAblA")
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(columns-1):
            arr[i][j] = int(file.readline().rstrip("\n"))
        print(arr[i])
    print("-------------------------------------------------")

    for k in range(rows):
        print(arr[k])

matrix()
```

why are these 2 "for" loop gives me different output like this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poVyw.png)

Comment: I suspect the code you've shown us isn't the code that generated that output. The output of the second loop in that image is the final row over and over, implying you actually printed `arr[i]` while looping with `k`

Comment: The problem is that you're performing a shallow copy when you originally create `arr`. Try `arr = [[0 for _ in range(columns)] for _ in range(rows)]`

Comment: No u got this something wrong ı guess. My purpose is reading data from text and add into array which is arr. I do that on first 2 for and ı just wanted to see like a chart thats why I wrote print end of the second for. Then ı want to add some values on the last column which is 8. But ı couldnt cuz ı cant reach to the correct values. These 2 prints gives different outputs. If u want u can try

Comment: for jdowner: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/ isn't it the same thing ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: @Kemp The code is correct. You could test it for yourself by removing the file stuff and filling the array with, say, `arr[i][j] = random.randrange(10)`. The problem is that all the rows are copies of the same list.

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mre] including input, plus output as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea Ah yes, I missed the creation of the lists. Good spot.